# Go to the next same word in Vim without using search

Tags: vim, command, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut in Vim for going to the next word which is the same as the word cursor is on? It should work without typing the word with search command `/`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

<kbd>*</kbd> goes to the next matching word and <kbd>#</kbd> goes to the previous matching word. <kbd>*</kbd> is so useful it's sometimes called the *super star*.

Comment: Thanks! Are there shortcuts for the same but without highlighting the search results?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> are your friends ( forward and backward directions respectively )

Answer (score 6):

While all the answers here are correct, I thought it may be useful to provide a little more info.

What `*` actually does is perform a forward search for `\<word-under-the-cursor\>`.  Because this is just a search operation, you can then navigate forwards and backwards to the next occurrences using `n` and `N`.  This also means your previous search is lost.  `#` is exactly the same as `*` except it performs a reverse search.

The `\<` and `\>` in the search string are word boundaries in vim's regex language which is what makes this work so nicely.  It's also important to note that what is considered a "word" is determined by the `iskeyword` option.  See `:help word` for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to select the word **w/o** the boundaries? That is, I have a word to search, which appears as a sub-word in multiple places I want to find. For exampe: find "day" and match "Sunday", "Monday".

Comment: It's been quite some time since I've used vim extensively, but I don't recall a way to do this without adding your own mapping.  Something like ":nnoremap <leader>* :let @/ = expand('<cword>') <bar> normal! n<enter>" maybe.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, I should have updated this comment. I asked the question and found the answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/q/47063402/274579

Comment: Ah yes. The ol’ g prefix. That modifies how quite a few vim mappings work. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5):

To search the current word under the cursor use '*'.

to search backwards for current cursor word use '#'

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>gd</kbd> and its variants are also very handy.  It works slightly differently from <kbd>*</kbd>, in that it searches for the local declaration of the word under the cursor (or global declaration if none local exists).  You can then search through the results with <kbd>n</kbd> like you can with superstar, and it will skip comments.  It can be helpful when you're editing code.

```
:help gd
```