# How to find ("super-star") the word under the cursor without the word boundary modifiers?

Tags: vim, find

Vim's "super-star" operation (search and highlight for the word under the cursor) is super-handy. But it has the limitation of searching for the exact match of the *whole* word.

Is it possible to have similar functionality, but w/o the enclosing word-boundary brackets?

Update: Apparently I was too quick to post the question. Looking [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1), there's the answer.

Comment: There's no need to look elsewhere than Vim itself: `:help *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is in [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1) page: Instead of pressing <kbd>*</kbd>, use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

using <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> is probably the best solution, but for new vim users it might be interesting to know how this could be done pretty much from scratch:

`:nnoremap <expr> * "/".expand("<cword>")."/\<CR>"`

`map <expr>` means that instead of mapping to a literal key sequence, the right-hand side is an expression that is evaluated every time the mapping occurs and the resulting string is treated like the RHS of a normal mapping.

`expand("<cword>")` returns a string containing the word under the cursor, and `"\<CR>"` basically just means the enter key.

So in the end we get a mapping to `/<word under cursor>/`<kbd>enter</kbd>, where the word under cursor isn't inserted until the mapping is used.